# Animation for imageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

I have an image and i did an animation with :

```
- (void) spinWithOptions: (UIViewAnimationOptions) options {
    // this spin completes 360 degrees every 2 seconds
    //Spin rotate image
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 5.5f
                          delay: 0.0f
                        options: options
                     animations: ^{
                         self.rotateImage.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.rotateImage.transform, M_PI / 2);
                     }
                     completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {
                             if (animating) {
                                 // if flag still set, keep spinning with constant speed
                                 [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear];
                             } else if (options != UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut) {
                                 // one last spin, with deceleration
                                 [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut];
                             }
                         }
                     }];
}
```

and in my viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

        [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn];   
 }
```

and it's ok on i luanch the app , but if i get into another screen and then back t the first screen , the animation is stoped . Any ideea how can i modify this ?

Comment: do you want animation to be continued even if you navigation to another view controller?

Comment: Check the value of animating flag which you have used in completion block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `viewDidLoad` is called once and the code inside it are compiled once(tell/suggest me if I'm wrong here). So to start your animation when you come back to the view you need to call your animation code inside `viewWillAppear` method. Hence, each time your view appears the code inside `viewWillAppear` will get compiled again.

Snippet:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad:` is called only once, i.e. when the view is loaded into the memory.

you need to either implement the method inside `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` callback methods.